# Buying Bitcoins without verification and documents

Tags: buy-bitcoins, verification

I need to buy Bitcoins with Visa or MasterCard, but without verification and documents. The amount of purchase is large. Can you suggest such online services?

Comment: Sorry, product recommendations are off-topic on this site as they tend to not create long-term useful information. I suggest that you try a platform that is more focussed on day-to-day topics such as reddit.